# Can't access Internet although I have configured my IP address correctly

Tags: networking, 16.04

I am using a HP laptop with dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. I can't access the Internet in Ubuntu although I have configured my IP address same as Windows 10.

```
# ifconfig
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr dc:4a:3e:f5:43:08  
          inet addr:192.168.9.89  Bcast:192.168.9.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::de4a:3eff:fef5:4308/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:263 errors:0 dropped:6 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:74 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:19198 (19.1 KB)  TX bytes:9524 (9.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
         UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:6824 (6.8 KB)  TX bytes:6824 (6.8 KB)
```

Comment: You have an ip address, but do you have a default route and a nameserver?  What do you see when you `ip route list` and what about when you `cat /etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: what's the output of `rfkill list all` ?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX nm-tool`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For Internet access you should have 3 things correctly:

1. IP Address
2. Default Gateway
3. DNS Server

For permanent usage you should edit file `/etc/network/interfaces`. For temporary and testing use these commands (Replace addresses with the correct one in your network):

**For IP address:**

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.9.89/24
```

**For Default gateway:**

```
route add default gw 192.168.9.1
```

**For DNS server:**

```
echo "nameserver 192.168.9.1" > /etc/resolve.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo dhclient` And See If Your Problem Solves.

Comment: They already have an IP address - how would requesting a new DHCP lease help?

Comment: @ThomasWard: Maybe he only configured the IP address not other settings required for Internet access.

Answer (score 0):

You should try that

```
sudo lshw -c network
```

if you are connected from ethernet(cable) then check for it's logical name then do this

```
sudo dhclient -r
```

```
sudo dhclient "logical name"
```

then you should try

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

It should work.

Comment: He has an IP address already - he shouldn't have to go and get *another* `dhcp` lease

Comment: But it don't showing logical name by doing `ifconfig`, So first command will show it's logical name